# Múltiples gráficos en una slide de Rmarkdown

Tags: r, gráficas, markdown

Necesito hacer una presentación en html con Rmarkdown, en cada diapositiva necesito mostrar dos gráficos de la clase `dgr_graph` obtenidos con la función `process_map` del paquete `BupaR`. Por la clase de los gráficos, utilizo la función `render_graph` del paquete `DiagrammeR`, pero esto sólo me permite mostrar un gráfico a la vez.

De momento, este es mi código:

````
---
title: "Ejemplo"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(bupaR)
library(DiagrammeR)

#Realizo unos análisis previos a un csv
#Que finalmente son aplicados con la siguiente función
#La cual retorna un dgr_graph creado con process_map
graph<-function(subject,process_maps_type,criterion){
##
}

```

## First subject
```{r Etapa 1}

#Creo el primer gráfico 
graphic<-graph(first,"performance","partial")

#Muestra el gráfico
render_graph(graphic)

#Creo el segundo gráfico 
graphic<-graph(first,"frequency","partial")

#Muestra el gráfico
render_graph(graphic)

``` 
#Esta slide se replica de forma similar
````

Básicamente realizo todo un análisis previo para generar los gráficos, pero al gráficar me aparecen los dos gráficos en una misma 'columna' en vez de en una misma 'fila', por lo que el segundo gráfico aparece cortado al final de la slide. Me gustaría mostrar los gráficos una al lado del otro.

Saludos,

Answer (score 1):

Una posibilidad es combinar los dos gráficos en uno solo, usando [`combine_graphs()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/DiagrammeR/man/combine_graphs.html), un ejemplo podría ser:

```
library(DiagrammeR)

graph1 <- add_gnm_graph(create_graph(), 
                        n = 10,
                        m = 15,
                        set_seed = 23)

graph2 <- add_gnm_graph(create_graph(), 
                        n = 8,
                        m = 22,
                        set_seed = 23)

combined_graph <-
    combine_graphs(x = graph1, y = graph2)

# Display the combined graph
render_graph(combined_graph)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Acabo de probar `combine_graphs` y no me funcionó. Me arroja el siguiente error: ´Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator´. Atribuyo el error al al formato que poseen los gráficos, aunque es una mera suposición.

Comment: Además, hago una corrección: La función `process_map` es del paquete `processmapR` de mismo autor que `bupaR`, de ahí la confusión.

Comment: Lamentablemente sin un [mcve] es muy difícil darse cuenta el por que del error. Más allá de como construyas los gráficos, si es un gráfico válido para `render_graph` de `DiagrammeR`, debería ser posible combinarlos en uno solo. Trata de editar tu pregunta agregando los datos y el código mínimo para reproducir tu problema. Saludos.